# Diferenças de nota!

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma situação onde preciso validar as fichas que estão na contabilidade e as fichas que estão no financeiro. eu sei que na contabilidade tem 51 notas e no financeiro 52. Preciso montar a query de forma que me traga apenas essa nota excedente no financeiro, que é considereada diferença. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue a consulta a baixo:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
    TIPO,
    CODPARC,
    NUNICO,
    SUM(VLR) AS VLR,
    CODPROJ,
    CODNAT,
    CODTIPOPER 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
            'ESTÁ NA CONTABILIDADE' AS TIPO,
            NULL AS CODPARC,
        BINT.NUNICO AS NUNICO,
        SUM(LAN.VLRLANC) AS VLR,
        NULL AS CODPROJ,
        NULL AS CODNAT,
        NULL AS CODTIPOPER
        
    FROM 
        TCBLAN LAN JOIN TCBINT BINT ON LAN.NUMLANC=BINT.NUMLANC AND LAN.NUMLOTE=BINT.NUMLOTE AND LAN.REFERENCIA=BINT.REFERENCIA AND LAN.TIPLANC = BINT.TIPLANC AND LAN.CODEMP=BINT.CODEMP
    WHERE 
        LAN.DTMOV >= :DATA.INI
        AND LAN.DTMOV <=  :DATA.FIN
        AND LAN.CODCTACTB = (SELECT CODCTACTB FROM AD_CONFIGCART WHERE CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA)
        AND LAN.CODEMP IN (2,29,30,33,35)
        AND LAN.TIPLANC = 'R'       
    GROUP BY BINT.NUNICO

UNION

    SELECT
        'ESTÁ NA CONTABILIDADE' AS TIPO,
            NULL AS CODPARC,
        BINT.NUNICO AS NUNICO,
        SUM(LAN.VLRLANC) AS VLR,
        NULL AS CODPROJ,
        NULL AS CODNAT,
        NULL AS CODTIPOPER
    FROM 
        TCBLAN LAN JOIN TCBINT BINT ON LAN.NUMLANC=BINT.NUMLANC AND LAN.NUMLOTE=BINT.NUMLOTE AND LAN.REFERENCIA=BINT.REFERENCIA AND LAN.TIPLANC = BINT.TIPLANC AND LAN.CODEMP=BINT.CODEMP
    WHERE 
        LAN.DTMOV >= :DATA.INI
        AND LAN.DTMOV <=  :DATA.FIN
        AND LAN.CODCTACTB = (SELECT CODCTACTB FROM AD_CONFIGCART WHERE CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA)
        AND LAN.CODEMP IN (2,29,30,33,35)
        AND LAN.TIPLANC = 'D'   
    GROUP BY BINT.NUNICO)A
GROUP BY 
    TIPO,
    CODPARC,
    NUNICO,
    CODPROJ,
    CODNAT,
    CODTIPOPER)B
JOIN 
(SELECT 
        TIPO,
    CODPARC
        NUNICO,
        VLR,
    CODPROJ,
    CODNAT,
    CODTIPOPER
FROM 
    (SELECT 
    'ESTÁ NO FINANCEIRO' AS TIPO,
    FIN.CODPARC, 
    FIN.NUFIN AS NUNICO,
    (FIN.VLRDESDOB) AS VLR,
    FIN.CODPROJ,
    FIN.CODNAT,
    FIN.CODTIPOPER
    FROM 
        TGFFIN FIN
    WHERE
        FIN.DHBAIXA BETWEEN :DATA.INI AND :DATA.FIN
        AND FIN.ORIGEM = 'F'
        AND FIN.PROVISAO = 'N'
        AND ( FIN.CODNAT IN 
            (SELECT CODNAT FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL) 
        AND ( FIN.CODNAT NOT IN 
            (SELECT CODNAT FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL)
        
        AND ( FIN.CODPROJ IN 
            (SELECT CODPROJ FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA =:CARTEIRA ) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL) 
        AND ( FIN.CODPROJ NOT IN 
            (SELECT CODPROJ FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL)
        AND ( FIN.CODTIPOPER IN 
            (SELECT CODTIPOPER FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL) 
        AND ( FIN.CODTIPOPER NOT IN 
            (SELECT CODTIPOPER FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL)
        AND ( FIN.CODTIPTIT IN 
            (SELECT CODTIPTIT FROM AD_TITCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_TITCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL) 
        AND ( FIN.CODTIPTIT NOT IN 
            (SELECT CODTIPTIT FROM AD_TITCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_TITCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=2 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL)
        
UNION

    SELECT  
    'ESTÁ NO FINANCEIRO' AS TIPO,
    CAB.CODPARC, 
        CAB.NUNOTA,
        (CAB.VLRNOTA) AS VLR,
    CAB.CODPROJ,
    CAB.CODNAT,
    CAB.CODTIPOPER
    FROM 
        TGFCAB CAB
    WHERE
        CAB.DTNEG BETWEEN :DATA.INI AND :DATA.FIN
        AND CAB.CODEMP IN (2,29,30,33,35)AND ( CAB.CODNAT IN 
            (SELECT CODNAT FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL) 
        AND ( CAB.CODNAT NOT IN 
            (SELECT CODNAT FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_NATCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL)
        
        AND ( CAB.CODPROJ IN 
            (SELECT CODPROJ FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA =:CARTEIRA ) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL) 
        AND ( CAB.CODPROJ NOT IN 
            (SELECT CODPROJ FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_PROJCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL)
        AND ( CAB.CODTIPOPER IN 
            (SELECT CODTIPOPER FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = 1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL) 
        AND ( CAB.CODTIPOPER NOT IN 
            (SELECT CODTIPOPER FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) 
            OR 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AD_TOPCART WHERE INCEXC = -1 AND (CABFIN=1 OR CABFIN=0) AND CARTEIRA = :CARTEIRA) IS NULL))C)D ON D.NUNICO=B.NUNICO

WHERE 
    D.NUNICO<>B.NUNICO
```

Comment: só olhara pra query fica dificil ajudar (especialmente uma query grande como a sua), precisa colocar a estrutura das tabelas e exemplos de dados

Comment: Grosso modo um "outer join" testando a chave faltante (null) , nota?! , ou um "not exists" , no Oracle fazemos "minus" parece que o EXCEPT faz este papal no sql-server https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-except-statement-with-examples/

Comment: Qualquer tipo de ajuda torna-se difícil sem maiores detalhes. O teu problema parece ser específico para o teu negócio. Como sugestão você poderia montar um modelo genérico com tabelas, alguns dados e o que você já tentou fazer e não deu certo.